# PHP ignore 5th character?

Tags: php, syntax

I have a simple *php* question.

in my *php*, I have this:

```
$variable = 'howareyou';
```

is it possible to somehow modify the code so it only counts up to **6th** character of the variable?

so after, when echo'd

it would say *howare* instead of *howareyou*.

I need to filter it with a number, like **5th** or **6th**. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: php substr() function: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.phpwill just do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use substring.

```
$variable = substr($variable, 0, 6)
```

The syntax is substr(string, start, length) and remember that these are zero indexed.

Comment: Length is the number of characters you want. It should be 6 not 5.

Comment: @codaddict Correct you are, fixed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) to retrieve part of a string:

```
$substring = substr($variable, 0, 6);
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following code:

```
$var=substr($variable,0,6);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
echo substr($string, 0, 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note. If you use UTF8 (for example) and another non-english language or fancy UTF characters you will need the mb_(...) functions.
So `substr($string, 0, 6)` becomes `mb_substr($string, 0, 6)`

Otherwise you risk splitting a multibyte characted in half, and it isn't pretty. This also means that if there are multibyte characters the regular substr will count them as 2 resulting in much shorter string that you'd expect.